# Sorting fails in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, sorting

I've spent quite some time on this and not been able to uncover the bug here.

Essentially, I have a multivariate array of the type `var test_arr = [['79',0],['8',1],['30', 2],['580',3],['59',4]]` which I generate from a function.  It doesn't behave like a normal array, in that my sort fxn `var sort_arrays = function(a,b) {return a[0]-b[0]};` fails to properly sort the array values.

I've attempted to make sure that I have an actual array, and that I'm not calling an alternative sort method.

Hence:

```
console.log(arr_test.sort(sort_arrays));
```

Gives: `[[8,1],[30,2],[59,4],[79,0],[580,3]]`

However, calling this on my fxn,

```
console.log(input_kde.sort(sort_arrays));
```

, gives: `[...,[580, 0.002],[59,0.001]]`

In trying to generate some printable output, I called `.toString` on my result, and got correctly sorted output, which only solidified my confusion.

I've attempted explicit type casting with `parseFloat(a[0])` to no avail.

I've also tried to confirm that this really is an array:

```
console.log(typeof(input_kde)); //#> object
console.log(input_kde.constructor); //#> function Array() { [native code] }
console.log(input_kde instanceof Array); //#> true
```

Also, the input_kde[0] is an Array and input_kde[0][0] is a number

```
console.log(input_kde[0] instanceof Array); //#> true
console.log(typeof(input_kde[0][0])); //#> number
```

What have I missed?

**edit2**

```
var input_kde = [[22,0.0017095221275204712],[24,0.001712291003699343],[28,0.001716821328044571],[307,0.0009792081392809542],[33,0.0017205981968323918],[34,0.0017211029300063302],[341,0.0010085669284820244],[35,0.0017215244128879188],[387,0.0010558490092862406],[4,0.0016696065108796395],[40,0.0017223891946762664],[448,0.0010667514507313397],[491,0.0010124434821844265],[519,0.0009480280002363708],[580,0.0007465298453339767],[59,0.0017073128314605394]]
```

Comment: Other things to confirm: (1) That `input_kde[0]` is an array. (2) That `sort_arrays` is actually being called. (For debugging, you can temporarily add something like `if(! window.foo) { console.log("Called sort_arrays"); } window.foo = true;` so that it logs just the first time it's called.) (3) That `input_kde[0][0]` is a string.

Comment: @ruakh (2) `sort_arrays` is being called, as both .toString wouldn't give a correct answer and I use sort_arrays in the arr_test case.

Comment: Well... Assigning the result to a value seems to make it work.  Otherwise it returns an unsorted array.

Answer (score 0):

I might just be shooting in the dark here, but you have mixed types in there (string and int)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine  http://jsfiddle.net/w8T32/

```
var test_arr = [['79',0],['8',1],['30', 2],['580',3],['59',4]];
test_arr.sort(function(a,b){
    return a[0] -b[0];
});
console.log(test_arr)​
```

And the output is something like

```
[['8',1], ['30',2], ['59', 4], ['79',0], ['580', 3]]
```

One thing to consider is that sort does not have a documented return value (it modifies the array in place) but you seem to be using it. Change your code so it doesn't rely on the return  value and see if that makes any difference

Comment: @Ryanmt What does your comment mean? That you agree and are going to improve your question? If it isn't a surprise, why did you use it? You're just wasting the time of people trying to help you here by not putting enough effort into your question

Comment: My test case array does work.  I've shown that above, the problem I have is with the actual data, as in the input_kde.

Comment: Is there an alternative to `sort` that doesn't modify in place?

Comment: @Ryanmt No there isn't, but it should be easy to split out your code so it doesn't use the return value. Example `var arr = []; console.log(arr.sort());` becomes `var arr = []; arr.sort(); console.log(arr);` Also, your second example also works when I try it

Answer (score 0):

```
var input_kde = [[22,0.0017095221275204712],[24,0.001712291003699343],[28,0.001716821328044571],[307,0.0009792081392809542],[33,0.0017205981968323918],[34,0.0017211029300063302],[341,0.0010085669284820244],[35,0.0017215244128879188],[387,0.0010558490092862406],[4,0.0016696065108796395],[40,0.0017223891946762664],[448,0.0010667514507313397],[491,0.0010124434821844265],[519,0.0009480280002363708],[580,0.0007465298453339767],[59,0.0017073128314605394]]



    //test run
    var sorted=input_kde.sort(function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]});
    alert(sorted);
```

I can't find anything wrong!!!!

Actually, why your code fails to return the correct value in the second run is because you have set the variable `sort_arrays` already with the previous one!! Hence, failed!

Comment: Apparently I'll never understand Javascript.  Where did I assign something to sort_arrays?

Comment: Modify you code this way if you want it to work - function sort_arrays(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]} ; now evrything should work fine, eg:- var sorted=input_kde.sort(sort_arrays);alert(sorted); var sorted2=test_arr.sort(sort_arrays);alert(sorted2);

Comment: why your first code fails to work is sort_arrays=function(a,b){return a[0]-b[0]} has already had some values in it when you run over with your first array, that is, test_arr and so it is not same anymore as what it was before!